# 12/2 wire home run from one building to the other where the panel is (about 100’)

Tags: electrical

I’m trying to run 12/2 home run wires from a bedroom and another 12/2 home run wire to my other tiny house that has the electrical panel.
The distance is about a 100’ home run for each room (bedroom and kitchen).
They will have separate breakers.
Do I have to bury the home run wires in the ground with gray pvc, or can it be above ground either in the pvc or metal conduit attached to the outside of the buildings?

Comment: Quite certain it needs to be buried.  The powers that be do not like unprotected wire lying around, even in conduit.  Conduit not much protection from mowers or being run over from vehicles.  A 100 feet at almost the distance 12/2 is useful.  Might be okay for lights/clock radios.

Comment: Actually, conduit attached to the outside of building, perhaps a foot above ground level (there's likely a best practice height) should be fine, as long as it is schedule 80 PVC conduit, or rigid/IMC/EMT metal conduit (liquid tight/weatherproof connections/fittings). PVC or PVC-jacketed metal liquidtite flexible conduit should also be OK IIRC attached to a wall above low-level ground hazards.

Comment: So I couldn’t attach it to the outside on the building which sits two feet above the ground in either gray pvc or metal conduit?

Comment: Also, whether underground or above ground, even conduit outdoors is considered a "wet location", so you can't use Romex for your run outdoors. I'll let the experts here suggest what makes sense in your situation.

Comment: Does the "tiny house" already have electricity running to it?

Comment: There are *multiple* issues with this. One is that you can only have two separate circuits to an outbuilding if they are fundamentally different (typically switched lights .vs. constant power) but you could run a multiwire branch circuit if you actually have 240V service at the starting point. If you are crossing open space between the buildings, rather than running along a 100 foot long building, you either need to go up and run on poles with adequate clearance below, or you need to dig down to bury the conduit. If your circuits are not different, you should run a feeder to a sub-panel.

Comment: The existing tiny house has electricity already and I have room in the electrical panel to add the breakers.

Answer (score 1):

(non-expert partial answer)

Yes, you can use schedule 80 or outdoor metal conduit or similar along the side of the building. Since conduit outdoors is considered a "wet location", you can't use Romex wire; you can use THHN/THWN dual rated wire (W for "wet") and there will be rules about how much wire "fill" is allowed for a given diameter conduit. Any junction boxes/fittings need to be weatherproof (e.g. liquid tight for EMT) and there are rules for how often support/attachment is needed.

From a YouTube video ["How to run 220-240v from your basement to your garage without digging using conduit and THHN"](https://youtu.be/eDkVINoWwek)(actually THWN):

[image]